# Call functions of one class (JS Scoping)

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var example2 = {
   test1: '',
   test2: '',
   ctrlId: 'a-control-id',
  ctrl: $('#a-control-id'),

  init: function() {
     this.fTest1('var1', 'var2'); //good
     this.ctrl.on('click', fTest2); //good
     fTest1('v1', 'v2'); //good
   }

  fTest1: function(test1, test2) {
     this.test1 = test1;
     this.test2 = test2;
  },

  fTest2: function(test1, test2) {
      this.fTest1(test1, test2); //undefined
  }
};

example2.init();


<div id='ctrlId'>test</div>
```

When the click event is fired the `fTest2` function is fired but `this` is `null` and `fTest1` thus cannot be run.

I would like to create an object or function that i can use for say a product display where after initalization properties maintain their values and I can call other methods of the object/nested functions.